# Installing openCV on MATLAB with mex and MinGW64

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex, mingw-w64

I'm trying to install OpenCV on MATLAB2015b using [mexopencv](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv). I have downloaded and successfully installed *MATLAB support for MinGW-w64 C/C++ Compiler* add-on in MATLAB. This is MATLAB's suggested compiler when I type `mex -setup`. However, when I run `mexopencv.make` in MATLAB, I get the following error:

```
Error using mexopencv.make>pkg_config (line 333)
OpenCV library path not found: D:\opencv\build\x64\mingw\lib
Error in mexopencv.make>mex_options (line 265)
[cv_cflags, cv_libs] = pkg_config(opts);   
Error in mexopencv.make (line 82) 
mex_flags = mex_options(opts);
```

I have already added mexopencv-master directory to my MATLAB's Path. And I have already checked that I have downloaded the correct version of opencv for mexopencv (which is 3.4.1 as of now).

I don't know why `\build\x64\mingw\lib\` doesn't exist. I have seen different tutorials but most of them use Microsoft Visual Studio 2013/2015 C++ to compile mexopencv. How can I compile OpenCV with MinGW-w64 on my own? Or is there another github package that I should've downloaded instead of this one?

I have tried to uninstall my current version of Visual Studio and install the 2013 version to use its C/C++ compiler. However, MATLAB doesn't recognize this compiler when I issue `mex -setup`.

Any help is appreciated. Also, I cannot use MATLAB's computer vision toolkit because I want to use a function that is not supported by it (Namely, the probabilistic Hough transform).

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv) the tool you're using? Please clarify this in your question. There is extensive instructions in the README file, including which specific branch of OpenCV you need to clone and build. Did you do these things? Please [edit] your question to contain all the steps you've taken so far. We cannot look in your computer, so cannot know what its configuration is, and therefore depend on what you tell us here. So far, it looks like you didn't install OpenCV as directed by the instructions.

Comment: There's an alternative tool here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47953-computer-vision-system-toolbox-opencv-interface

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I will edit my question to address the points you made.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I edited my answer. I hope that it's clear now.

Comment: This is clearer, sure. Did you follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/wiki/Installation-%28Windows%2C-MATLAB%2C-OpenCV-3%29) for building OpenCV? That page was linked from the README for mexopencv. It looks pretty complete and detailed. In CMake you can select MinGW as your toolchain (see for example [here](https://github.com/tudelft3d/masbcpp/wiki/Building-on-Windows-with-CMake-and-MinGW) for instructions in a different project).

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Yes. I have followed all the instructions on that page. It gave me a Visual Studio solution file. Then I opened it in Visual Studio and it said that it was incompatible. In other words, I have read the instructions, but I have not understood them fully. Maybe CMake is not using MinGW? I mean, if it has already used MinGW to compile it, then why do I need to use a Visual Studio solution file? It just doesn't make sense to me and I'm terribly confused. :(

Comment: CMake doesn’t compile, it creates makefiles. Configure CMake for the MinGW toolchain, make the makefiles, then use the mingw32-make program to build OpenCV.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks. Now it makes sense. I will try that and let you know the result if you don't mind.

Comment: Note that Visual Studio does not install C/C++ by default. If MATLAB does not recongize it using `mex -setup` the most likely case is that you isntalled Visual Studio, but not the C/C++ compiler. go to `Control panel>Add or remove programs -> Visual studio community 20XX -> modify` And check if C/C++ is there